# How to print the text dynamically on the image in html using angularjs in two way binding method?

Tags: html, angularjs

In this code the text is printing on the side of the image but I need on the image so please help me to finish. Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Sample</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="connection">
    <div class="container">
      <form> <br> Enter The Text :
        <input type="text" ng-model="Username" name="Username"><br><br>
        <img src="DHONI.jpg">{{Username}}
        <div class="centered"></div>
        <button ng-click="submit(Username)" hidden>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var App = angular.module("myapp", [])
    App.controller('connection', function($scope) {
      $scope.submit = submit;

      function submit(Username) {
        $scope.name = Username;
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the `{{ Username }}` in a `<div>` and give it `position: absolute`. Also wrap the `img` and this `div` inside a parent `div` with `position: relative`. See code below:

```js
var App = angular.module("myapp", [])
App.controller('connection', function($scope) {
  $scope.submit = submit;

  function submit(Username) {
    $scope.name = Username;
  }
});
```

```css
.ctn {
  position: relative;
}

.u-name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Sample</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="connection">
    <div class="container">
      <form> <br> Enter The Text :
        <input type="text" ng-model="Username" name="Username"><br><br>
        <div class="ctn">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          <div class="u-name">{{Username}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="centered"></div>
        <button ng-click="submit(Username)" hidden>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```